# Append textbox and buttons to a particular section of div

Tags: jquery

```
$("#id_attach_btn").click(function() {
    if(count<4) {
        $("#id_blank").append("<br><input id='' type='file' name='file' /><img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/upload.bmp' width='80' height='30'/><img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/delete.bmp' width='80' height='30'/>");
        count++;
    } else {
        alert("Cannot attach more than four file in single attempt");
    }
});
```

Can we append a div on the basis of id in append function ?
Here i have written too much code in append() function is there any way to pass a id of a div which contains that code?

Comment: what is **count** and how do you get it?

Comment: define variable like this: var myvar = '<br>....';

Comment: can't find any problem with your fiddle mate.check it http://jsfiddle.net/SRZ7L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the HTML in a hidden div, and extract it using jQuery's .html() method before appending it to the other div:

```
$("#id_blank").append($("#inputholder").html());
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/5PLrq/

See documentation at http://api.jquery.com/html/